# How to obtain the variance n dimensional points?

Tags: r

I want to know how to measure the variance of  n-dimensional points, in these case i have the following n=24 points, how can i find the variance between them?

```
               V1  V2  V3   V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24
118116770  33  36  34   20  17  43  70  46  40  25  20  31  86 173 149  62  28  34  35  35  21  16  36  36
2532712   479 983 909 1035 723 678 423 192 210 271 155 176 277 397 247 150 255 446 370 250 320 227 348 219
2532704   297 360 542  550 317 316 294 282 393 316 202 145 152 175 190 189 249 247 231 188 267 206 202 235
2532697    70  47  70  107 220 159 116  77  70  50  73  67  56  80  58  97 163 188 163 196 202 191 184 163
2532696   358 615 740  745 521 387 161 226 288 256 255 408 404 521 382 341 309 293 368 369 158 221 413 455
755706    196 253 307  297 231 157 122  90 124  95 160 142 150 178 145 154 138 117 137 150 165 127 140 114
1488012   130 390 449  463 496 394 152  78  76  74  71 166 191 224 159 120  60  92 179 180 178 213 147 144
```

Each row is a point of 24 dimensions.

Comment: How are you defining variance in this case? Can you point to some definition you want to use?

Comment: I'm obtaining the mean of this data set. So i want to obtain the variance as the squared deviation of that mean.

Comment: And how are you calculating the mean? Per row? per column? When you ask for the "variance between them" exactly how many values are you expecting? Is this a matrix? A data.frame?

Comment: I'm expecting one value. The mean is per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var(df)` gives you covariances for every pair of columns. Since Cov(A,A) = Var(A), you want the diagonal of `var(df)`. This can be done using `diag()`. So getting the variance of every column in a dataset you can use:

```
diag(var(df))
```

Comment: I am sorry, you need to use `var` instead (without capital V).